# Lost important Wordpad document when power went out--seems to be gone--need magic to make it reappear

Tags: windows-7, documents, wordpad

I was writing a lengthy important document, using Wordpad first to edit--editing one paragraph at a time, then copying/pasting each completed paragraph to Focus Writer (because it has more options and much simpler use) "just in case". Just as I was almost done with the most lengthy & tedious paragraph, the power went out. I've searched all over the internet for answers. I've looked through TEMP files for the date and approximate time. I found an unreadable dated the approx. time. How can I decipher it, and if it's not the Wordpad copy I am looking for, are there any tricks (no cost) to make it magically reappear? Please help! This paper is very stressful to write and took a lot of psyching up to even begin it. In Focus Writer, it saves as a .odt file, and when I reopen it, Wordpad, instead of Focus Writer, automatically opens it. Focus Writer automatically saves my work and reopens to where I left off. My other partially edited copies appear to all end up as .odt files. I did periodically hit "save" on Wordpad, but only see the .odt copies that Focus Writer saved. *Thank You* for your expertise.

Comment: You are out of luck.  Wordpad doesn't have the feature your looking for. You not only want the impossible you want it free.  I wish you luck in writing your paragraph again

Answer (score 1):

Unless you changed the "save as" type in [WordPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad), it will normally save files as [Rich Text Format (RTF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (.rtf) files. If you didn't select Open Document Text (.odt) as the file format when saving the document in WordPad, look for a .rtf file, which typically would go in your Documents directory, but which you could have saved in another directory.

You stated that .odt files open in WordPad by default; if you want to open one in Focus Writer, instead, simply right-click on the file in the Windows [File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer), choose "Open with" and select Focus Writer to open it in that application. But, if you don't see the missing text when you view the file in WordPad, you likely won't see it in Focus Writer, either.

However, assuming you did choose to save the file in the [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) format in WordPad, though, so that the unreadable file you found was created either by WordPad or Focus Writer, you could check on whether it could possibly be an OpenDocument file, though without the expected extension or a possibly corrupted .odt file, by using a [hexadecimal editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor). On Microsoft Windows systems, I use the [Freeware Hex Editor XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) for files 2 GB or less in size - I would expect that if the file was created by WordPad or Focus Writer that it would be less than that size, so you should be able to open it in that utility.

If it is an OpenDocument .odt file, you should see "mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocment.text" near the top of the window in the right pane, where the utility shows the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code for the file's contents - at least if the file was created by WordPad, though I would expect the same or similar text to be placed there by Focus Writer as well. I've included an example screen shot below.

[image]

If you see that text in the unreadable file, you could give it an .odt extension to see if you could open it in WordPad or FocusWriter. If it is an .odt file, but without the expected extension, you could also make a copy of it and give it a .zip extension, because the .odt format is an [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)-based file format with XML files contained in what is essentially a compressed [zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) file. If you make a copy of the file and give the copy a .zip extension you can then unzip the contents - I would make a copy so the original is still available to possibly use some other utility on it, if, perchance it does hold your missing data. If you can unzip the zip file, you will see files within the .zip file like the ones below:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9420-A68C

 Directory of C:\Users\Public\Documents\test

08/30/2017  09:31 PM    <DIR>          .
08/30/2017  09:31 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/31/2017  01:26 AM             3,140 content.xml
08/30/2017  09:31 PM    <DIR>          META-INF
08/31/2017  01:26 AM             1,378 meta.xml
08/31/2017  01:26 AM                39 mimetype
08/31/2017  01:26 AM             1,828 styles.xml
               4 File(s)          6,385 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  75,399,454,720 bytes free

C:\Users\Public\Documents\test>
```

You can open the the `content.xml` file with Notepad or Wordpad to see your content, i.e., whatever you typed into the file, which you could then copy and paste elsewhere, if somehow the file could be unzipped, though WordPad nor Focus Writer could open it.

I'm not sanguine about your data being in the unreadable file and the chances of recovering the lost data from the unreadable file, if that's where it is, rather than that file being created by some other application on your system near the time the problem occurred, but in desperate circumstances I would try anything I thought might possibly recover the data.

Also check `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\WordPad` where `YourName` is  your account name on the system. According to the person who posted [Recovering unsaved Wordpad files after Windows 8 forced reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/855159/recovering-unsaved-wordpad-files-after-windows-8-forced-reboot), WordPad uses that folder for temporary files. You may need to [make hidden files and folders visible](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/explorer/folder-options/#Win7) in the Windows File Explorer to locate that directory and view its contents, if you try to access it from the File Explorer.

Comment: Wow--thank you SO much for the info--which will help in the future,too. I am going to try each suggestion and then come back and let you know. I've been combing the internet--infinite--I could've re-written the darn thing 3X over. I wanted to at least try also learn something.The reason I allowed WPD to continue open it, is it made it handy it to edit and use Focus Writer to save it--it's so long and cluttered with edits, it started getting confusing-the paragraph is really 2 pages long, to be divided later. My battery doesn't charge, and if I bump the cord it shuts down and  why I saved often

Comment: Just a quick check in to let you that I found an rtf file--thank you--it's invaluable!  And I downloaded the Hex Editor and I am going to figure out how to use it. I am also going to try doing a zip file as you suggested. Thanks a million!  If it works it will be a big Hallelujah--and if it doesn't, at least I know I tried  :)  And learned a lot along the way!

Comment: I did have hidden files and folders open. It's taking me so long because I am finding files in which the permissions are all mixed up, and other tweaks along the way. Also, my Windows Search in the Startup folder doesn't work, and neither does Windows Help (but I will check for answers to those in the archives here another time :/)

Comment: I forgot to say: I am now trying to find a way to make the rtf tmp file readable via your suggested methods.

Comment: Update: I haven't been able to read the file.